# How avoid global installation of npm packages

Tags: node.js, npm

I use linux system for development. I'm trying to create react native application:

```
npm init react-native-app myproj
```

It finishes with message:

*This command requires Expo CLI.
Do you want to install it globally [Y/n]*

If I say "no" the installation stops.

I've tried to install expo-cli and then create react native app:

```
npm install expo-cli
npm init react-native-app myproj
```

It finishes successfully, but when I try run application it shows the message about necessity of global expo-cli installation again.

In general the packages exist to keep the linux system clean.
So I wonder why npm have ability of the global installation, at all? It contradicts at least the linux package system and make the system volnurable.
Why It does not have an option to install packages in $HOME/.npm (global for user) for example, where the cache is located and when some package is required npm could search the package in $HOME/.npm directory if it had not been found in global directory?

Where am I wrong?

Comment: What problems do you see with installing the package Globally?

Comment: I'm not for the garbage on my file system. Everything is installed not from linux packages is considered as the garbage. For example npm can create something in /usr/bin. For example when one compile some unix software its default root path  for application /usr/local in order to protect super user from running substituted executables

Comment: I guess its matter of preference. Installing packages globally in node is common and I don't see any issues with it personally. If the packages you are installing are stable and very active there are no concerns. Generally. a package should be installed globally when it provides an executable command that you must run from shell. Also, if its reused across projects it makes sense as well.